# Android Wear Intent from notification not firing

Tags: android, android-intent, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I am writing a small Android Wear App, and part of what it does is creating an ongoing notification with two actions: 1. Open the app again. 2. Close (clear the state) of the app.

The first action (open) works perfectly (ie.: I press the button, the action is executed). But the second action does not fire anything.

Here is the code of the notification itself:

```
    // First action: open app's main activity
    Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, actionIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Action action =
            new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.close_button,
                    getString(R.string.open_app), actionPendingIntent)
                    .build();

    // Second action: clear the state of the app, by firing a service which will do so
    Intent tnsIntent = new Intent(this, TimerNotificationService.class);
    PendingIntent tnsPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, tnsIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Action closeAppAction =
            new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.close_button,
                    getString(R.string.close_app), tnsPendingIntent)
                    .build();

    return new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.time_tracking_on))
            .setContentText("Tap to open app")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setOngoing(true)
            .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(action).addAction(closeAppAction))
            .setLocalOnly(true)
            .build();
```

Note: I tried instantiating the tnsIntent in another way `Intent tnsIntent = new Intent(ACTION_TERMINATE_TRACKING, null, this, TimerNotificationService.class);` but it did not change anything.

The service looks like that:

```
public class TimerNotificationService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        clearSomeState();
    }
}
```

I ran the app in debugging mode and put a breakpoint in the `onHandleIntent()` of the service and I did not hit the breakpoint, so the service does not even receive the intent. Did I miss some intent-registration call that I should be doing somewhere for the service maybe? (in the manifest?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `tnsPendingIntent` is launching a `Service`, it should be set from `PendingIntent.getService`, not `PendingIntent.getActivity` as your code snippet shows. ([reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)))

Comment: Good catch! That was indeed one of the problems.

The main problem, though, was that I had to declare my service in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the (wear) application. Without that, Android would just never call it: _"All services must be represented by <service> elements in the manifest file. Any that are not declared there will not be seen by the system and will never be run."_ ([reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html))

If you can include it in your answer, that'd be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I actually considered mentioning that, but since you hadn't posted your manifest, I decided it would be presumptuous to critique it. :^) Glad you got it sorted!